# useContext throwing a warning that the 'context' in [context, setContext] is unused. If I remove it that app crashes

Tags: reactjs

as the title states, useContext throwing a warning that the 'context' in [context, setContext] is unused. If I remove it that app crashes

in my code I have `const [context, setContext] = useContext(whatever)`, the warning the dom throws is `Line 12:10:  'context' is assigned a value but never used`.

However, if I remove `context` (which im not using here) so that i just have `const [setContext] = useContext(whatever)`, the program crashes saying `TypeError: setContext is not a function`.

How do I get rid of the warning without breaking the system?

Comment: `const [, setContext] = useContext(whatever)` Looks weird, but that's the syntax for destructuring only index 1 of an array.

Comment: thanks, i wouldnt have guessed that... what about the other way. i want context, but not setcontext const [context] = useContext(FormContext); do i need a comma after context? @NicholasTower

Comment: No, you do not need a comma for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nicholas Tower for the answer

```
const [, setContext] = useContext(whatever)
```

Looks weird, but that's the syntax for destructuring only index 1 of an array. You do not need the comma to remove the second destructured function of the hook